# Inserting JavaScript variable inside php echo and reading it as a variable not a string

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hello I have this simple problem in my code. I'm using php echo to use my javaScript inside in my model, my question is I want to use my JS variable inside php echo and pass it through url using GET method my problem is my variable is read as string a variable

```
echo  "<script>
         $('.btnclick').on('click', function(){
             var ris_id = $(this).attr('data-id');

             window.open('pdf_report?d="."ris_id"."' , '_blank');
         });
       </script>"
```

Here's my sample code, my problem is that I want to pass the ris_id as a variable not a string to the new tab that will open after click the button.

Comment: Avoid using `echo` if your output has no PHP in it. Just close the PHP context with `?>` and write your plain HTML / JS as normal

Comment: Alternately, simply use a template literal which means nothing to PHP... `window.open(\`pdf_report?d=${ris_id}\`, '_blank')`

Comment: I can't avoid using the echo because the button is generated from the model and the "<script>" must be echo so that I can use the "<script> </tag>"

Comment: There is absolutely no difference between `echo "<script>...</script>";` and `?><script>...</script><?php`

Comment: using <?php <script></script ?> inside a php function gives me error

Comment: Seems fine here ~ https://3v4l.org/JB6tk

Comment: I just solved it :D I transfer my js script to a external file so that I will not use the echo anymore. thanks for the response guys.

Comment: None of that output you are creating there is "dynamic", it does not depend on any PHP values or conditions - so it should have been written without echo to begin with. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use simple javascript not jquery.

Answer (score -1):

The concatenation of string in JS or jquery will be done by (+) not by (.)

```
window.open('pdf_report?d="'+ris_id+'"' , '_blank');
```